# Git Merge deletes new files of base branch

Tags: git, branch

We are having a develop branch, and many different feature-branches. Now we have an extern developer, who created a feature-branch, and made an pull request to our repository (https://github.com/massiveart-webservices/ZOOLU/pull/7).

Now I have the problem that every change made in our develop-branch since the extern developer created his feature-branch gets deleted, if I try to merge his branch. You can see this on the pull request, e.g. on the file library/massiveart/generic/fields/Imagemap/data/helpers/Imagemap.php.

As far as I know git merges all the commits from the other branch into the desired one. So I thought that these files should not be deleted, as they are not deleted in any commit of the extern developer (in his repository these files even don't exist). So my question is why git tries to delete this files, and how to resolve this issue.

I have also told him to pull the changes from our developer branch into his feature-branch, but the result was not satisfying...

Comment: Yes, a merge should create a superset of the changes on both sides. If the files never existed in the history of the feature branch, they should not get deleted in the merge.

About merging the other way: The result of a merge should not depend on the direction, the only difference is in which branch is updated to the merged version.

Comment: So my assumptions were right. But you can see in the link to the pull request that the files get deleted... Or did I miss something? And by the way, the result is the same if I pull the changes on my local repository...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific file you mention goes missing because of a mis-merge in commit [75326832600d0034138ec7bc15000d4cfcd50d3d](https://github.com/NurbekChymbaev/ZOOLU/commit/75326832600d0034138ec7bc15000d4cfcd50d3d). A correct merge would have added the file (since a merged version is supposed to be a superset of all changes in the merged branches), but this one didn't, which is equivalent to a deletion of the file on the branch.

Comment: Are we talking about the commit with the message "decrease snippet preview description chars count to 156"? Where do you see that there has been a mis-merge?

Comment: At the point of the previous merge, the base branch did not have the file yet, and it does have it at the point of the new merge, so it was obviously added between these points. On the feature branch, the file has never been added. Since it was added on one side and not modified (not present) on the other, the merged version should contain it, but it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get the point... You mean that the file got added between the commit you mentioned and the pull request, which I want to merge now. I am quite sure that this is true, but that means also that the file has never existed in the feature-branch. So it should not be deleted during the merge, shouldn't it? You also say the merged version should contain it, so why does it not?

Comment: Not between the commit I mentioned and the feature branch, no. Look at the Network graph: There are two merges from your master branch into the feature branch. Between those two merges, the file was added in the master branch, so it is a change that should be present in the result of the second merge (on the feature branch), but it isn't. As for why it is missing, ask the person who did the merge, not me. My best guess is that he only wanted to merge some of the changes from master, but that is not what a merge is for (cherrypick would be the right weapon there).

Comment: Ah, ok, now I got the point. The other developer is not aware of the fact he did this... So it probably was an accident.